# Проблема с браузером firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, firefox

сайт без адаптивности
При уменьшении примера в браузере хром и во всех остальных кроме мозилы. сайт уменьшается под размеры окна. а вот в мозиле размер сайта остается прежним и появляется горизонтальны скрол. вот пример https://mars092.github.io/test/
откройте его в мозиле и увидите. приложу свои скрины с хрома и мозилы.
как сделать чтобы мозила отображала сайт как хром?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gclmb1

Comment: скришот хрома       ---------

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gclmvs

Comment: скрин мозилы ---------

Answer (score 0):

Очистите кэш в Google Chrome. Это делается с помощью `CTRL+ENTER`
**------- Дополнения ------**
В браузере Google Chrome не видно скролл, но он есть, попробуйте курсором провести.
Вся проблема из-за правила `min-width: 1280px;` какое установлено в `body`

Comment: это тут причем?

Comment: @mars, дополнил

Comment: наоборот все, что бы мозила отображала также как хром!

Comment: min-width: 1280px; что бы это правило нормально работало на мозиле

Comment: @mars, https://yadi.sk/i/SJl1QgkB3MJU3a

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gclxga все в порядке, даже на разрешении в 320px

Comment: @mars, сделайте бордер черного цвета(допустим) в толщину 1-2пк с левой стороны и с правой. И поймете о чем я)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gcm4qh вот, добавил

Comment: на гитхаб тоже залил

Comment: @mars, https://yadi.sk/i/UsJOpAbe3MJVhs вот у меня не видно правого бордера. Может у Вас кэш старый, вы пробовали CTRL+ENTER

Comment: конечно побывал, на двух компах тестил

Answer (score 0):

Это баг хрома, а не мозилы, он в responsive mode не учитывает ширину. Вам надо добавить meta viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброго дня.
min-width - задает минимальную ширину контейнера к которому применили это правило. Соответственно сейчас ни о какой адаптивности речи не идет. У вас используется сетка bootstrap, вы не понятно с какой целью добавили min-width: 1280px для body и width: 1280px для .container в результате сломали сетку.

Если хотелось задать максимальную ширину, то это делается max-width.

Если хотелось, перезаписать значение максимальной ширины контейнера, то это можно сделать так:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1280px;
    }
}
```

Но лучше это делать переменными less - @container-lg

Успехов!